# Return the correct number of weeks in a year

Tags: vb.net, calendar

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720804/week-number-input-returns-crazy-full-week-output) I asked the community for support on how to display a week based on the requested week number. That question has now evolved into a question of how to display the correct number of weeks in a year.

I've started with this method based on input I've gotten from other threads within the StackExchange network, yet it displays the wrong week value.

```
Protected Friend Shared Function GetNumberOfWeeksInAYear(ByVal GetYear As Nullable(Of Integer)) As Nullable(Of Integer)
            Dim RequestedYear As DateTime = New DateTime(GetYear, 12, 31)

            Return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(RequestedYear, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, FirstDayOfWeek.System)
        End Function
```

The year parameter represents the requested year (as an integer) and the return value is also a integer representing the return number of weeks. This method is used to set navigational buttons in a custom calendars week view I'm building.

Now for some testing. 2003 had 52 weeks while 2004 had 53 weeks. I've confirmed this by comparing various calendars. The code above though returns 53 for 2003 and 52 for 2004. I've tried to add a year to the input but it won't change the output.

How should I improve the method to get it to output the correct week value?

Comment: How do you define "the number of weeks in the year"? You say you've "compared various calendars" but that doesn't give us any real information. The answer you get to the question depends on *precisely* what you deem to be "the number of weeks in the year" which can be determined in a number of different ways.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx for some subtleties, for example.

Comment: I've compared the calendars in Outlook, iOS and various paper calendars with week stamps in the margin. They all confirm that 2003 had 52 weeks while 2004 had 53 weeks. Of course I cannot tell what methods were used to calculate the week number. The article you referred to contains some pretty interesting reading though.

Comment: i guess leap years have 53 weeks and others have 52 check whether year is leap year or not You can test it

Comment: It isn't quite that simple. The closest full number to 365/12 leaves us with some excessive days that are treated as that 53rd week every now and then. The some of excessive days made up from leap years leaves us with an additional week every 28th year giving us 54 weeks. This could be calculated but I'd rather let the built in calendar function handle these occurrences - if I only learn how to use it. :)

Comment: "They call confirm" doesn't tell us even *slightly* what you consider to be the definition of "the number of weeks in a year". You haven't even told us what you did to confirm the number in those calendars. Until you can give us a precise definition of what you want, we can't tell you how to achieve it.

Comment: I believe I did answer your question @Jon Skeet. I told you I compared them with each other. I could put in other words. I read the margin column of each calendar where the week number is displayed. They all read the same value, hence I've confirmed it. I don't know how they reached those conclusions but since there are more than one calendar source giving the same information I would like to believe that they are correct. You partially gave me an answer in your second comment. By reading it I think i now understand how to calculate week numbers in relation to on which weekday a year begins.

Comment: You didn't mention comparing the week number in the margin before. That is what was missing. But you still seem to think there is one "correct" answer... Whereas it actually depends on what definition you use. All you've really checked is that those calendars probably use the same definition. There is no global well-defined idea of "correct" here.

Comment: Actually I did in my first comment. :) anyhow... I exaggerated when I assumed there was one "correct" answer to this. You are right, there are probably several ones. As mentioned in the blog you referred to there are different date standards to account for when determining the number of weeks in a year. I'll dig deeper into this knowledge. Thank you for your valuable input! :)

Comment: Okay, apologies for missing that "week stamps" part. But it sounds like we're at least on the same page now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Public Shared Function NumberOfWeeks(dateFrom As DateTime, dateTo As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim Span As TimeSpan = dateTo.Subtract(dateFrom)

    If Span.Days <= 7 Then
        If dateFrom.DayOfWeek > dateTo.DayOfWeek Then
            Return 2
        End If

        Return 1
    End If

    Dim Days As Integer = Span.Days - 7 + CInt(dateFrom.DayOfWeek)
    Dim WeekCount As Integer = 1
    Dim DayCount As Integer = 0

    WeekCount = 1
    While DayCount < Days
        DayCount += 7
        WeekCount += 1
    End While

    Return WeekCount
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the overall problem. Dividing by seven to figure out the closest whole number of weeks only accounts for treating leap years and ordinary whereas those occurrences where the year is divided into 54 weeks won't be calculated for. I haven't tested this yet, so I apologize if I'm wrong here, I just air a suspicion of mine. :)

Comment: well you can test it & let me know :)

Comment: Absolutely. I'll test it tonight when I get home from work and then give you feedback on it.  :)

Comment: Actually - stupid question by me, but... dateTo and dateFrom... those don't happen to be December 31st any year and January 1st any year respectively are they?

Comment: yup you are right these are supposed to be 1st jan and 31 dec respectively

Comment: I tried this solution and it actually works. :) thanks @Dandy for pushing for this approach. The only thing left is this: I'm using this calculation to determine the destination url for week navigational buttons. Whenever I pass New Year's Eve the the week grid displays the dates for week 1. When I navigate to week 2 however that same week reloads again. Week 2 is then displayed when I navigate to week 3 and so on... This bugs me a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should turn on `Option Strict` as you are passing a wrong type to `Calendar.GetWeekOfYear`:

```
GetWeekOfYear(Integer theYear, rule As System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule, 
       firstDayOfWeek As System.DayOfWeek)
```

The last parameter, `System.DayOfWeek`, is not the same thing as the `FirstDayOfWeek` enumeration in the VisualBasic NameSpace.  The VB one is for use with the VB `DateAndTime` Type, not the Net `DateTime` type.  When you turn on Option Strict, the compiler complains about the type mismatch.

This uses the "sv-SE" culture to get the week count for the various rules:

```
Dim cult = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE")
Dim cal As Calendar = cult.Calendar

' First Day
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay.ToString,
                  cult.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(RequestedYear,
                  CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, 
                  cult.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek).ToString)

' first four day
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek.ToString,
                  cult.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(RequestedYear,
                  CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,
                  cult.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek).ToString)

' first full week
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek.ToString,
                  cult.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(RequestedYear,
                  CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, 
                  cult.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek).ToString)

' WRONG - requires Option Strict OFF - VB enum
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", "VB FirstDayOfWeek Enum",
                  cult.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(RequestedYear,
                  CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, FirstDayOfWeek.System).ToString)
```

The output:

```
FirstDay - 53
FirstFourDayWeek - 53
FirstFullWeek - 52
VB FirstDayOfWeek Enum - 52
```

The way you probably want to use it:

```
    ' just to make things shorter
    Dim cult = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

    Return cult.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(RequestedYear,
                                        CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
                                        cult.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
```

The net result is that you were forcing the calendar to always use Sunday as the first Day of Week rather than Monday as defined in `DateTimeFormat` for the `sv-SE` culture.

Comment: Very interesting comment. I will take all this into consideration. I haven't tested it yet, but I guess this is an approach I really should investigate further. Thanks for a really sight full answer. :)

Comment: The first parameter should be the last day of the desired year `New Date(RequestedYear, 12, 31)`